# Facebook 'Message Us' plugin unable to resize to sizes small and medium

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger

When the size of the facebook 'message us' button is set to a size of small or medium then the facebook API returns an error 500. Facebook developer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/message-us-plugin) clearly states that medium and small should be accepted. What is the reason for this? Is there a fix?

```
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
     messenger_app_id='<%=FacebookAppId.ToString() %>'
     page_id='<%=FacebookPageId.ToString() %>'
     color="blue"
     size="small"
     style="margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>
```

Error code:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

This works fine:

```
<div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
     messenger_app_id='<%=FacebookAppId.ToString() %>'
     page_id='<%=FacebookPageId.ToString() %>'
     color="blue"
     size="large"
     style="margin-bottom:10px;">
</div>
```

Comment: please put the error codes in the question (not picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error in the documentation that has now been fixed. Accepted values are standard, large, and xlarge.